# How automatically update the table in in database using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, database

the problem is that how i automatically update the max_quanty table
i want to check the availability of order with respect to max_quantity
and when the order is confirm then the max_quantity table in database will automatically update

i am used this query to check the availability w.r.t to max_quantity.Its bulk_delivery table 
when user enter quantity the than the quantity value is subtract from max_quantity table

[image]

its bulk_delivery_order table
where the order information will store
[image]

the query to check availability is

```
SELECT *
          FROM bulk_delivery, bulk_delivery_order
          WHERE bulk_delivery_order.time='$order_time'
          AND bulk_delivery_order.date='$order_date'
          AND bulk_delivery_order.recipe_id='$order_recipe'
          AND bulk_delivery_order.restaurant_id='$order_restaurant'
         AND bulk_delivery.max_quantity-$quantityT"
```

plz guide me if i used wrong query

Comment: Issue is when user enter quantity value than this value will subtract the max_quantity table  and  max_quantity will  automatically update.and i dont know how i max_quantity table is updated

Comment: For, updating, you need an `update` query. You have a `select` query. First, check whether you have the required quantity using `select` query. And if yes, update the table using `update` query. You cannot do both in a single query.

Comment: update sometable set somecol=nnn where some_condition